# which platform supports BLE data packet length extension feature?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to use the LE Data Packet Extension feature (BT 4.2 spec). The Bluetooth stack host supports it on Android 6.0 according to some commits from Dec 18 2014.
However both Nexus 5 (with Android 6.0 AOSP) and Nexus 6 (with Android 6.0 AOSP) reports that the feature is not supported by the controller.

When calling "l2cble_set_fixed_channel_tx_data_length()":
controller_get_interface()->supports_ble_packet_extension()) returns FALSE.

Is there any Android platform that supports this feature?

Thank you!

Comment: I would like to know as well

Comment: From experience, Nexus 5x does. I have bought it and tried it. However, it seems the controller limits the packet to 119bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Google Pixel phones will support this feature. I tested with first generation Pixel. But first generation pixel phones have a maximum LE data length of 123 bytes whereas the maximum supported LE data length is 251 bytes.